# How can I get Intellij to stop underlining my scala code?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Basically, Intellij is making my code extremely hard to read by underlining lots of my code.  It kind of makes a chess board on the left of my screen  as well! =>

[image: Too many underlines!]

I have looked through the code editor settings but I can't find one under scala which controls these underlines. I am using the [twilight theme](https://github.com/eed3si9n/color-themes/tree/master/IntelliJ-IDEA/Twilight) but I have only just noticed the issue.  Any ideas Intellij buffs?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**IntelliJ 12:**

Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Scala -> Implicit Conversions
Uncheck "Effects -> Underline"

**IntellIJ 11 or Before:**

Settings -> Code Style -> Scala -> Other -> Other settings -> Highlight methods added via implicit conversion.
However anyway it's usability problem of this feature. Something different should be done to highlight implicit conversion for such places.

Comment: appearently this has changed in Idea 12.. anyone knows where is it now?

Answer (score 3):

The attributes used for different kinds of highlighting are configured under Settings | Editor  | Colors & Fonts.

Answer (score 2):

In Idea 12, it can be disabled at Settings | Editor | Colors&Fonts | Scala | Implicit conversion. I just unchecked Effects but it's also possible to choose something else than Underscore.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To disable underlining in JSP/HTML I usually click the little man in a hat in the bottom right corner and set highlighting levels to None:

[image: inspector]

I think it should be the same with Scala

Comment: oh I didn't notice that your underlines are not being produced by inspections

Comment: np, i learned about the little hat man which is good to know as well ;p