# Intellij HTML underline issue

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason all my HTML code on IntelliJ IDEA is underlined. It is very annoying. Is there anyway to remove it?

Here is an picture of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Jfn.png

Comment: Maybe possibly potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082228/how-can-i-get-intellij-to-stop-underlining-my-scala-code

Comment: Also note that `<center>` is deprecated in HTML (see http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html). This might be the reason you're seeing the underlining as part of IntelliJ's help to you

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it:

Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> HTML -> "Effects -> Underline"